# Не подтягивается css-файл на хостинге

Tags: css

Ребят, какой-то бред получился. Сделал код, на компе все нормально работает  но когда загрузил сайт на хостинг, то настройки моего css не активны, браузер их даже не видит. Из-за этого всплывающее окно стало отображаться как 
Вот сайт: http://rgho.st/65cJWZLYN

Comment: Я бы не скачивал неизвестный архив к себе на компьютер, а то мало ли :)

Comment: Проверьте пути к вашим файлам. Также проверьте, чтобы все файлы были в нижнем регистре.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, т.к. ссылка не рабочая, проверять нечего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Попробуйте добавить в ваш .htaccess строку:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

**Вариант 2**

Путь с `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` замените на `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

P.S. Пути указаны примерные, я не знаю точной структуры на вашем хостинге.

Answer (score 0):

Мучился 8 часов с этой же проблемой:
В файле index.html был неправильно прописан путь. У меня он был из корневой папки и до конца. Вот он был такой:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="/coding/lessons/lesson3/homework/css/style.css">
```

После того, как я выложил на GitHub pages меняешь его на:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/coding/css/style.css">
```

То есть GitHub pages обращается туда, где лежит твой файл CSS. Если ты пытаешься обратиться к файлам с рабочего стола в папках, то это обречено на провал.